# Azure IotEdge task on self-hosted Windows agent

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-iot-edge, azure-devops-extensions, azure-iot-sdk

We are running Azure IOT pipelines on our self-hosted Windows agents. Unfortunately it is throwing following error during the build pipeline

> ERROR: ('Could not connect to Docker daemon. Please make sure Docker daemon is running and accessible', DockerException("Error - while fetching server API version: (5, 'CreateFile', 'Access is denied.')"))

It seems we need to add some permissions for agent service.

We have installed Docker manually and Docker service is running with `localsystemAccount`.

Azure Pipelines agent service is running with **Network Service**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally issue got resolved after running the pipeline agent service with the same user that docker service is running on.